# ERRO: "normalmente é permitido apenas uma utilização de cada endereço de soquete"

Tags: c#, socket

Antes que digam que "a porta já está sendo utilizada, tente outra", eu já recebi essa resposta diversas vezes, e trocar de porta simplesmente não funciona.

Bom, estou desenvolvendo um jogo que usa Socket via UDP para transmitir dados pela rede, porém toda vez que instancio a classe UdpClient ele me dá o seguinte erro:

*"Normalmente é permitida apenas uma utilização de cada endereço de soquete (protocolo/endereço de rede/porta)"*

Esse é meu código:

```
        public void OnInit(Component.InitContext context)
    {
        if (context == InitContext.Activate)
        {
            servers = new List<ServerInfo>();
            renderers = new List<GameObject>();
            end = false;
            bool tryagain = true;
            while (tryagain)
            {
                try
                {
                    listener = new UdpClient(port);
                    tryagain = false;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    tryagain = true;
                    listener.Close();
                    Log.Game.Write(e.Message);
                }
            }
            ips = new List<string>();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(run));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
```

Fiz um loop na hora de instanciar o meu listener, porém ele fica no loop pra sempre, a variável port atualmente é a 11022, porém já testei com 11000, 11001, 11002, 11003, 1234, 7654, 9999, 123 entre outras que eu não lembro.

Tentei também acessar o comando netstat pelo cmd para verificar quais portas estão sendo utilizadas, antes de rodar o programa, nenhuma das portas citadas aparecem, porém após rodar o programa e o erro aparecer, a porta então aparece no netstat, e depois de um tempo some.

Também fui instruido a alterar um registro chamado ReservedPorts no caminho HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/Tcpip/Parameters, adicionando a minha porta, porém parece que esse registro não existe

Aliás na verdade esse erro só acontece as vezes, quando mudo de computador ou de pasta, nas primeiras vezes o programa consegue acessar a porta normalmente, depois parece que não consegue mais. Talvez eu não esteja fechando a porta direito, porém meu código tem essa parte:

```
 public void OnShutdown(Component.ShutdownContext context)
    {
        end = true;
        listener.Close();

    }
```

então a porta teoricamente deveria estar fechada ao terminar o programa, certo?

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Você não precisa usar a tag `visual-studio` quando o problema não for com a IDE.

Comment: Como você esta declarando o seu listener?

Comment: UdpClient listener; como uma variável global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um *listener* se vinculando à porta `port` em modo exclusivo. Para indicar vinculação compartilhada, inicialize seu UdpClient da seguinte maneira:

```
listener udpServer = new UdpClient();

listener.Client.SetSocketOption(
    SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

listener.Client.Bind(localpt);
```

Comment: Funcionou! Porém a linha
`listener.Client.Bind(localpt);` 
dá erro de argumento inválido, porém apenas tirar ela parece que faz funcionar

Comment: @vilok600 a 3a linha é bem dependente da sua implementação - não existe nenhum problema em retirá-la. Fico feliz que tenha funcionado!

Comment: Bom, acho que foi um alarme falso, funcionou umas 3 vezes, mas agora parou de funcionar de novo :/ Como eu estou tentando implementar multiplayer, tenho dois computadores de teste, um desktop e um notebook, o engraçado é que os dois estão acessando o mesmo arquivo de projeto, localizado no desktop, porém no notebook funciona perfeitamente, não deu erro sequer uma vez, então talvez isso seja problema do próprio desktop mesmo, ou do tipo de mapeamento de pasta, sei la